# JavaScript to make div visible after click

Tags: javascript, html, visibility

I currently have a button that I would like open a hidden div box that will then show a list to open a second div box. The code does not seem to be working for the JavaScript.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
$('#content1 div').each(function(i){
$(this).addClass('level1');
});
$('#content2 div').each(function(i){
    $(this).addClass('level2');
});

$('#menu2 a').click(function (e) {
    $('#content1 div.makeVisible').removeClass('makeVisible');
    $(divToMakeVisible).addClass('makeVisible');
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('div.level1 a').click(function (e) {
    $('#content1 div.level1').removeClass('makeVisible');
    divToMakeVisible = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(divToMakeVisible);
    $(divToMakeVisible).addClass('makeVisible');
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('div.level2 a').click(function (e) {
    $('#content2 div.level2').removeClass('makeVisible');
    divToMakeVisible = $(this).attr('href');
    $(divToMakeVisible).addClass('makeVisible');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The full code on JSFiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/nkxsP/20/

Comment: The main problem is that you are using jQuery and didn't mark in jsfiddle to use it. On top-left corner select jQuery 1.9 to use it.

Comment: Even with enabling jQuery 1.9.1 the page still does not seem to work. Any other suggestions?